# Dynamic loading of spring integration context files (or routes)

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have spring MVC application where in I will be loading the multiple components (jars) in run time. Each component can create its own topic/queue. I also need to build a special integration route (including channel and other components) when I load the new component. And delete the route when I remove the component. I was thinking dynamically generating a spring xml file with routes and load into container. Is this possible or do I have any better alternatives

Answer (score 0):

The [`dynamic-ftp`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) sample uses that technique...

It uses the Spring 3 environment feature to pass in properties to each instance of the context. If these contexts need access to elements (channels etc) in the main context, you can make the dynamic contexts a child of it. That is discussed [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?128303-Dynamic-Inbound-Channel-Adapter-creation)...

Comment: Thanks Gary. This example helps partially. In my case even the sources will be dynamic. I am planning to add a new queue on the fly to the RabbitMQ and create a route from the new source to existing destination. and vice versa. Create new destination queue/http (or jms) end point on the fly and create a route from existing source to the new end point.